# Always on top html block for iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

How can I create a DIV block that always stays at the bottom of my page? When scrolling more content should show up right above the block. The only solution i can think of is to use 2 iframes but I prefer using CSS.

Update: The solution needs to work on iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some CSS:

```
.bottomFixed {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    /* technically not necessary, but helps to see */
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Here's some HTML:

```
<div class="bottomFixed">Hello, world!</div>
```

This div would be placed at the bottom of the screen and stay there.  Note: this won't work on iOS because of the way it does scrolling.

Comment: is bottom:0 the bottom of the current screen or bottom of the page? I need it to show at the bottom of the current screen

Comment: Bottom of the screen for position:fixed

Comment: Just saw the update about iOS - on iOS, it's still the bottom of the "screen", but the display is just a viewport over the window's client area, so position: fixed doesn't work there.  From what I've read, this is not possible on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

```
div.bottom {
  position:fixed;
}
```

Then just move it where you want. Unfortunately, browser support is limited. IE6 for example doesn't support this option for `position`. Also note that this removes the `div` from the flow, so you'll have to make sure there's enough space for the viewer to see stuff at the bottom of the page with the `div` on top.

Comment: I don't know the screen size, how can I make it stay at the bottom?